# How to get defined local variable to combobox as values in python?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, combobox, local-variables

I am working on a project where I required defined function variable(local variable) in the values of **Combobox** but it gives me error of **undefined variable**. And **I cannot change the pattern of my python script** otherwise the script will mixed up and gives other error.

Please help me to solve the problem without changing the script pattern.

Here is my code:-

```
book= ''
pages = 1
page_no = 1
pdfReader=''
def selectBtnClicked():
    # pass
    global book
    global PDFFILE
    global pages
    global page_no
    global pdfReader
    print(PDFFILE)
    # PDFFILE1=pdf_btnClicked()
    book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
    pages = pdfReader.numPages
    print(pages)
    pages += 1
    page_no = [i for i in range(1, pages)]
    print(page_no)
    return page_no, pdfReader

#start from
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly','red')])
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', 'red')])
style.map('TCombobox', selectforeground=[('readonly', 'white')])
n= tk.StringVar(value="---STARTING PAGE---")
n.set("---STARTING PAGE---")
startfromLabel = ttk.Combobox(root, font=font, justify='center', textvariable=n)
startfromLabel["values"]= page_no
# pages_nos()
startfromLabel["state"] = "readonly"
startfromLabel.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>')
startfromLabel.current()
startfromLabel["foreground"] = '#ffffff'
startfromLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
  
root.mainloop()
```

I need **page_no** as value of **startfromLabel** but I am not getting the values in my GUI output:

[image]

Comment: Post the full error code please

Comment: I had edited my code and uploaded my full code

Comment: What is the error? You still did not mention the error you got.

Comment: I am not getting the values in my gui output

Comment: Just post the part of code that is important or causes this error.

Comment: Sir, I edited and give the essential part where I am unable to get the values(list) in combobox in my gui

Comment: Try saying `startfromLabel["values"] = page_no` inside the function too

Comment: Ive added an answer, to mark the Q closed

Comment: ok sir, I had upvote answer and again I am very thankful to you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not telling to change the `values` inside the function, so say:

```
def selectBtnClicked():
    .... #same bunch of code
 
    startfromLabel["values"] = page_no
    .... #remaining bunch of code
```